# Is the HTML / JavaScript event handling exactly the Chain of Responsibility design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, event-programming, event-handling

Just except that Chain of Responsibility might go one straight line, but in the HTML event handling, it is first the "capture phase" (capturing), then the "at phase", and then the "bubble phase" (bubbling), so it is Chain of Responsibility by going from the first item to the end and back to the first item.

And any item that is suitable for handling it will act on it, by registering an event handler.

Comment: I don't see that Wikipedia page talking about HTML event handling, but saw Apple's Cocoa event there: *Typically, when a view receives an event which it can't handle, it dispatches it to its superview until it reaches the view controller or window object. If the window can't handle the event, the event is dispatched to the application object, which is the last object in the chain*

Comment: Apparently it is.  See http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern.  It was the first match in a Google search for the title of your question.